# determining trustee of directories on novell netware volume

Tags: novell

Currently there are a lot of directories (user home directories that may no longer exist) on a netware volume. As this number is significant, I'm in need of an easy way of determining if there are any trustee's (existing users who have permissions to the directory) on the directories in question.

So, several things I'm after.

1) Are there any applications, that take the input of a list of directories and output the same list with the trustee's attached?

2) Is there an easy way to determine the trustee's without looking at Console One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a tool called TrstRpt](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/1834.html) from Wolfgang Schreiber you can download ([download link](http://wstools.hyperphp.com/files/trstrpt.zip)).

Answer (score 1):

Trustee.nlm should be included with Netware after 6.0.  It generates a trustee.xml file with an XML representation of the trustee list.

[TBackup](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/13961.html)which was written in the NW4.11 time frame is one of my favorites still, and works fine if you client 32.  It has not been updated in a while, but pretty much works fine.

Condrey Consulting has a commercial product called [TrustFun](http://www.condreycorp.com/Source/Products/TrustFun/Overview.html) that does this very well.  (Much of its functionality has been rolled into the new File Management Suite from Novell, which does way more and in interesting ways)

There are a bunch of other tools that could do this for you, but I got bored of looking them up after three.